# Understand some specific cases of the constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class X {
public:
    X () {
        x = 0;
        cout << "1";
    }
    X (int x) {
        this->x = x;
        cout << "2";
    }
    X (double x) {
        this->x = x;
        cout << "3";
    }
    X (const X& x) {
        this->x = x.x;
        cout << "4";
    }
protected:
    int x;
};
class Y : public X {
public:
    Y () : X(10) {
        cout << "5";
    }
    Y (int p) : X(p) {
        cout << "6";
    }
    Y (const X& x) : X(x) {
        cout << "7";
    }
    Y (const X& x1, X x2) : X(x1), x(x2) {
        cout << "8";
    }
protected:
    X x;
};

int main() {
    Y y1;
    cout << endl;
    Y y2(10);
    cout << endl;
    Y y3(y1);
    cout << endl;
    Y y4(y2, y3);
    cout << endl;
}
```

The output of this code is :

```
215
216
44
4448
```

- In the first two cases, I don't understand why there is the '1'. I agree that the object is built with the second X constructor and the first of Y but why the first constructor of X is called after the second one ?
- In the third case I would like to know why there is no '7' because in my opinion the program declares a Y instance so a Y constructor should be called ?
- In the last case, there is a '8' so that sound good to me but why there is three X constructor call whereas y2 and y3 are already declared ?

PS : I apologize for my English mistakes and I thank the people who correct me

Comment: Hint for 1) There are two objects to initialize in `Y`. The variable `x` and the ... :)

Comment: You do not have explicit  copy-constructor for Y - so when it is called - you see no output from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Y` derives from `X`, and *also* contains a data member `x` of type `X`. When instantiating an object instance of `Y`, an `X` constructor must be called for *both* the inherited `X` portion of the `Y` class, *and* the `x` data member.

In the first 2 cases, the `Y` constructors you are calling are not *explicitly* initializing the `x` data member, so the compiler uses the default `X()` constructor to initialize it *implicitly*.  That is where the `1` comes from.

In the 3rd case, `7` is not output because you are not constructing the `y3` object with an `X` object as input. You are constructing it with another `Y` object. But you haven't *explicitly* defined a `Y(const Y&)` copy constructor, so the compiler defines an *implicit* copy constructor for you, which invokes the `X` copy constructor twice, once for the inherited `X` portion of the `Y` class, and once for the `x` data member.

In the last case, you see `4` being output 3 times because you are invoking the `X` copy constructor 3 times, two *explicitly* and one *implicitly*:

- when passing `x1` to `X()`
- when passing `y3` to `x2` (which [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/) `y3`, because `x2` is pass-by-value)
- when passing `x2` to `x()`

Comment: I almost understand all your explanation, but in the first two cases I'm still not understanding which line are calling the default `x()` constructor because the line `Y () : X(10)` is used for the first case hence this line calls the constructor which take a int parameter. So why the compiler uses the default `x()` constructor whereas all the objects are built ?

Comment: @Lodec: as I said in my answer, the first 2 cases are not initializing `Y`'s `x` data member **explicitly**, only the inherited `X` portion of the `Y` class, so the compiler is **implicitly** calling the default `X()` constructor for the `x` member. Remember, `Y` has 2 `X`s in it, not one